# Android: How to align Linear Layout inside FrameLayout to bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have the following layout structure:

[image]

I need to align the second LinearLayout to bottom in way that if any part on view inside of the second LinearLayout became visible, the second layout should be resized to be still visible.

How can i do that in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: is it necessary for you to use `FrameLayout` here???

Comment: I think that yes, because bottom layout should be above the first one, because can be expanded above the first LinearLayout without shrinking the screen.

Comment: but that is something you can achieve with `RelativeLayout` also.

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute layout_gravity to align any view inside a FrameLayout

```
<LinearLayout ...
android:layout_gravity:"bottom"
/>
```

But if you are trying to place it at the bottom of some other layout. Then use relative layout instead.

> Example

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="some text view"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:background="#123123"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="some text view at top inside "
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="some text view at second position "
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: result of above code]

For your question "the second layout should be resized to be still visible."

It is better to use RelativeLayout.
Assuming your second LinearLayout is at the bottom of the RelativeLayout. 
If it has no child view, it will be invisible if its height is set to `wrap_content`. And whenever you add some views to it. It shall resize-itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use gravity attributes like

```
<LinearLayout
  android:width="match_parent"
 android:height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity:"bottom">
```